# como o google vê paginas dinâmicas

Tags: php, google, otimização

Olá amigos uma duvida de noob,
Eu desenvolvo sites em PHP.
o que acontece, no lugar de ter 50 paginas uma com cada categoria eu uso uma página com while.
Bom quando se escolhe uma categoria uma outra página é aberta, também dinâmica, que pega o ID dessa categoria e monta essa página com as informações do banco.
então na pagina fica o endereço www.xxx.com.br/pagina.php?id=5.
Quando o ID é X mostra uma coisa, quando o ID é outro mostra outra.
Como o google consegue , se consegue indexar minhas categorias.
Supondo que 5 fosse "Carros", e que quando acessa essa pagina com esse GET mostre carros.
A pessoa faz uma busca sobre carros, essa pagina minha aparece ? 
ou eu tenho que crair uma página para cada categoria, para cada cliente para cada produto no meus site ?

Comment: Somente pelo URL da página de exemplo já é possível saber que seu site está mal otimizado para o Google. Parâmetros de URL não são favoráveis. Pesquise por URL Amigável. Dessa forma poderá ser: xxx.com.br/carros/1, xxx.com.br/carros/2. O "`/carros`" será a página, o "`/2`" será o id, coletado normalmente via `$_GET['id']`, obtendo `2`.

Comment: _PS: O termo dinâmico é ambíguo, porque parece ser referente a `Javascript`, ou seja conteúdo carregado `dinamicamente`.)_

Comment: em relação sua pergunta, já fiz teste e o google indexou normalmente as páginas que são utilizadas com id dessa forma, mas tente trocar número por palavras, fica mais fácil a leitura.

Comment: Vocês não me entenderam, acho que me expressei mal, vou tentar se claro.

Comment: O google olha minha pagina ficticia: resultado.php, nela esta escrito,
{Mostra tudo do banco que tenha ID tal}
1 linha de cógio, se for ver o aqruivo resultado.php.

Comment: alguém no google busca a palava carros (que com ID certo a resultado.php tras os carros)
Só que lembrem o arquivo só tem uma linha de código, no arquivo a palavra "CARROS" não existe, ela vai existir se entrar na pagina via browser com um determinado ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para o google encontrar a sua página basta registrá-la, no google. Mas para ela aparecer entre as primeiras páginas, se usa **Motores de busca**, que são técnicas para melhorar a classificação da sua página.

## Estrutura das Páginas.

As páginas devem estar estruturadas corretamente de acordo com as normas sintáticas, o uso de `section`, `article`, `nav`, `metas` e `h1`, influenciam consideravelmente quando o google buscará sua página.

## Redes Sociais

É importante que sua página seja conhecida, isso ajuda com que o google encontre mais rápido.
Se sua página tem perfies no *facebook*, *twiter* e *google*, aumenta as chances da página ser encontrada para cada pessoa que segue sua página em uma dessas redes sociais.

## Outros Sites

Se houver links, de sua página sendo citados em sites famosos, aumenta o status da sua página, e ela sobe cada vez mais para o todo da pesquisa.

## Quantidade de Acesso

Uma página bastante acessada é jogada para cima com muita facilidade.

## Atualização do Conteúdo

Uma página com conteúdos atualizados toda semana pelo menos, é bem vista pelos motores de busca.

## Pague

É possível pagar para que sua página fique em primeiro lugar, se eu não me engano é coisa de centavos por clique.

## PDFs

**[MB: Uma nova alternativa para o aranha](http://www.inf.ufpr.br/bona/tg-acg.pdf)**

**[Optimização para motores de busca](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/www.google.com/pt-BR//intl/pt-PT/webmasters/docs/guia-optimizacao-para-motores-de-busca-pt-pt.pdf)**

**[Motores de busca](https://futurocomtic.files.wordpress.com/2011/04/motores-de-busca.pdf)**

Answer (score -4):

e simples, entre na sua página e vê o Open SourceForge (código fonte da página ) se for possível ver o conteúdo dinâmico significa que o Google também poderá verificar o conteúdo do site, então essa é a forma como os rastreadores conseguem visualizar os sites dinâmicos , mais a classificação vai depender se o seu site e seo frindly ou nao